# enquiry about cable adapter charger

Tags: laptop, cable, charger

I just bought an laptop acer travelmate it come with an original charger but his plug cable has three pins (like in pic above) a guess it's a italian plug.

I am wondering if can i use my current cable (EU) with this charger?
Is there any problem just simply using it? 
Do i need to buy a plug adapter (EU) to use it with this italian cable?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The shape of the cable has nothing to do with the usage within EU. You need to look at the power supply and verify it is made for the 220V system that is used in Europe.

Most modern adapters will work with 110 - 240 V so you just need to get the right cables but there are exceptions. If the power adapter says 110V or something else than 220 or 240, do NOT use it.

otherwise you are fine

Comment: the power supply say 110-220V so i can use it with my old cable laptop(EU) ?